# Finding the limit of $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^{log(n)}}{(\log n)^n}$

Tags: limits, logarithms

I try to calculate the following limit:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^{\log(n)}}{(\log n)^n}$$

I tried this:

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} e^{(\log(n))^2 - n \log(\log(n))} $$

Is this useful? & what do now?

Comment: What do (you do) now? Compute the limit of the exponent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is useful. Now, you could try to look at $\log^2 n - n\log\log n$ and see if it converges or diverges to $\pm \infty$ -- any of the two will give you the limit you're looking for.

As a start, rewrite
$$\log^2 n - n\log\log n = n\left(\frac{\log^2n }{n} - \log\log n\right)$$
In the parenthesis, the second term goes to $-\infty$. What about the first?

Comment: n also goes to infinity. infinity * 0 can go to anything.

Comment: @mathreader It is not quite a case of "$0\times\infty$." In the parenthesis, you have "$(0-\infty)=-\infty$." You then multiply the parenthesis by $n$, which goes to $+\infty$.

Comment: $ \inf * - \inf $ ...isn't that not defined?

Comment: No: it results in $-\inf$. (To see why, think of the definition: for any $M>0$ the first quantity stays $> M$ after a while, and the second $< -M$ after a while... thus, the product stays $<-M^2$ after a while.

Comment: Yes you are right Clement. But the explanation was not very clear.

Comment: @mathreadler: Erm... How did you interpret "In the parenthesis, the second term goes to $-\infty$. What about the first?"?

Comment: @ClementC. Well constructed tutorial! +1